# Add an image to a views title (Taxonomy Term View)

Tags: 7, views

I have a view listing nodes of my taxonomy terms. All well and good and my view shows nodes of every taxonomy term with the taxonomy term name as the view title.

My taxonomy terms though have an image assigned to them. So is there any hook or any other way to show the taxonomy term title next to its corresponding image? Something like this?

**Example image:**

> [image]

And here is a screenshot of the view. Notice the path that is taking the term id as a parameter to display nodes of a specific term.

EDIT: I am using the default Taxonomy Term View

**Views UI**

> [image]

Comment: *My taxonomy terms though have an image assigned to them.* How did you assign the image to taxonomy term?

Comment: I created an image field. So every taxonomy term has an image also.

Comment: Can you please paste a screen-shot of your Views UI Setting section, So it is very easy to answerer to understand. So, everybody can be on same page and can give you better suggestion.

Comment: I edit the question. Is it clear enough now or you want me to elaborate more?

Comment: One question, While creating views, one very first page, you have a option of choosing Views of............... Did you choose Content or Taxonomy term?

Comment: Content...I am displaying the content of every taxonomy term. My view has a title (The term name) and below is the listing of every content that is assigned to this term. I don't think there is a way to add the image of the taxonomy term title via UI. Do you have any clues how to do this through a hook?

Comment: I will be interested to see teh answer. I tried, even I found the way to change the title, but displaying the corresponding image is somewhat tricky. Please edit your question. You have used the `Taxonomy term` View which is provided by default in the view, Please mention that, that is the important.

Comment: @CodeNext see the answer below.

Answer (score 2):

I would use [Panels](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels) for that. You may combine any elements from Drupal on the same page (node fields, views, terms, blocks, etc.) with Panels.

With this module you can edit the taxonomy term page as you wish (Structure > Pages > Taxonomy view > Active then edit).

In the Content section, after setting path, context and layout, you add your taxonomy term custom image field, followed by your taxonomy term name (with a little CSS float, you will have your image on the left).

Finally, you add your View below (do not forget to activate the Chaos tools sub-module "Views content panes") and you're done.

Panels needs a little practice but it is a powerful tool to work on page templates.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Toki I figured out a simple solution using [Context](https://www.drupal.org/project/context) instead of [Panels](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels).

1. I created a new view of taxonomy terms with a contextual filter of Term ID provided by the URL. In my View I have a limit of one item to display, and I show only the term name and icon field without anything else.
2. I created a block and using Context I placed my block to the Term Pages (I don't think this is needed because the Block will only show up in Taxonomy Term pages anyway, because of the Contextual Filter).
3. I added some css and done.

Sometimes we complicated things. Thanks again @Toki for the main idea.